# MySQL Varchar not recording interger only

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

$argUser - MySQL set to VARCHAR(15).

If I post letters everything works.
If I post letters and numbers, everything works.
If I post just numbers... it doesn't record the entry...

I'm using the CodeIgniter Framework and this is my function for recording log in attempts:

```
function testCredentials($row, $argUser) {
    $this->log_attempt = $argUser;
    $this->log_time = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $this->log_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if ($row->user_regid == $argUser) {
        $this->log_success = 'TRUE';
        $this->db->insert('logins', $this);
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->log_success = 'FALSE';
        $this->db->insert('logins', $this);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the $argUser.  Everything else works as expected.

Comment: Print the query. Or, if you don't know how to do it, turn on MySQL general log.

Answer (score 0):

do not use varchar for storing date and time.

you can use MySql *datetime* datatype to store php date (date("Y-m-d h:i:s");)

Comment: Sorry.  Issue isn't with Date/Time.  It's with $argUser.  If only a int is entered it will skip inserting the entire row.